# Python: New list grouping repeated elements from existing list

Tags: python, list, grouping

I have one list of the form:

```
>>> my_list = ['BLA1', 'BLA2', 'BLA3', 'ELE1', 'ELE2', 'ELE3', 'PRI1', 'PRI2', 'NEA1', 'NEA2', 'MAU1', 'MAU2', 'MAU3']
```

and I want to create a new list, grouping the repeated elements into lists inside my new list, so at the end I will have:

```
>>> new_list = [['BLA1', 'BLA2', 'BLA3'], ['ELE1', 'ELE2', 'ELE3'], ['PRI1', 'PRI2'], ['NEA1', 'NEA2'], ['MAU1', 'MAU2', 'MAU3']]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`itertools.groupby`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
import itertools

[list(group) for key, group in itertools.groupby(my_list, key=lambda v: v[:3])]
```

The `key` argument is needed here to extract just the part of the value you wanted to group *on*; the first 3 characters.

Result:

```
>>> my_list = ['BLA1', 'BLA2', 'BLA3', 'ELE1', 'ELE2', 'ELE3', 'PRI1', 'PRI2', 'NEA1', 'NEA2', 'MAU1', 'MAU2', 'MAU3']
>>> [list(group) for key, group in itertools.groupby(my_list, key=lambda v: v[:3])]
[['BLA1', 'BLA2', 'BLA3'], ['ELE1', 'ELE2', 'ELE3'], ['PRI1', 'PRI2'], ['NEA1', 'NEA2'], ['MAU1', 'MAU2', 'MAU3']]
```

`groupby` will combine successive keys that are equal into 1 group. If you have disjoint groups (so same value, but with other values in between) it'll create separate groups for those:

```
>>> my_list = ['a1', 'a2', 'b1', 'b2', 'a3', 'a4']
>>> [list(group) for key, group in itertools.groupby(my_list)]
[['a1', 'a2'], ['b1', 'b2'], ['a3', 'a4']]
```

If that is not what you want you will have to sort `my_list` first.

Comment: sorry, I did not explain myself correctly.

my list is:

>>> my_list = ['BLA1', 'BLA2', 'BLA3', 'ELE1', 'ELE2', 'ELE3', 'PRI1', 'PRI2', 'NEA1', 'NEA2', 'MAU1', 'MAU2', 'MAU3']

And i want to obtain:

new_list = [['BLA1', 'BLA2', 'BLA3'], ['ELE1', 'ELE2', 'ELE3'], ['PRI1', 'PRI2'], ['NEA1', 'NEA2'], ['MAU1', 'MAU2', 'MAU3']]

Comment: @user2208885: Not sure what is missing in your explanation then; your input and output are matched.

Comment: Yes, what you answered was correct, was my mistake in the explanation of the problem ^^

Answer (score 1):

Make sure it's sorted and use

```
itertools.groupy
```

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to groupby, you could use [`collections.Counter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#counter-objects):

```
In [40]: from collections import Counter

In [41]: [ [k]*v for (k,v) in Counter(my_list).iteritems() ]
Out[41]: 
[['PRI', 'PRI'],
 ['NEA', 'NEA'],
 ['BLA', 'BLA', 'BLA'],
 ['MAU', 'MAU', 'MAU'],
 ['ELE', 'ELE', 'ELE']]
```

This will work without the need to sort the list if the elements are all jumbled up, unlike groupby.

Comment: With the updated question, your solution no longer works, I fear.

Comment: @Martijn - so I see.  In that case I would go with your updated solution.